# How can you interact with the Windows desktop when using TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, ui-automation, e2e-testing, testcafe

I need to use TestCafe to perform actions within our Electron app, however I also need to perform actions on the Windows desktop (e.g. click taskbar, launch other apps).

Since TestCafe can only interact with what is within the browser window, I have attempted to use Appium to essential run TestCafe (calling the commandline from C#) and then performing the Windows desktop actions through WinAppDriver however this feels like a kludge.

Are there other methods of arranging this or a framework that would be more elegant?

Thanks for any insights

m

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have successfully used [robotjs](https://github.com/octalmage/robotjs) to interact with the desktop (mouse move, click, etc.). This seems to be an excellent choice at the moment. Just install alongside TestCafe in your node project.

Answer (score 3):

You are right - TestCafe can only interact with what is within the browser window, but not outside it.

You can also check out the [testcafe-browser-provider-webdriverio](https://github.com/fnlctrl/testcafe-browser-provider-webdriverio) plugin. Its author claims that this provider can connect to an Appium server.

Comment: so looking at [the API usage section](https://github.com/fnlctrl/testcafe-browser-provider-webdriverio#usage) I could have my testcafe Electron script and Appium WinAppDriver script in the same script file but create different runners for each? And interleave calls to each.

Comment: I have not used that third-party plug-in. You might want to submit your inquiry directly to the repository so the author can provide you with a precise solution.

Comment: Asked the question here for those interested: https://github.com/fnlctrl/testcafe-browser-provider-webdriverio/issues/3